# Excel More conditions in one formula?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Can I have those conditions here packed in one formula?.

```
1. If the price (D2) is <= 20 and ROI (J2) is <= 10 then true or false.
2. If the price (D2) is between 20 and 60 and ROI (J2) is <= 5 then true or false.
3. If the price (D2) is between 60 and 150 and ROI (J2) is <= 4 then true or false.
4. If the price (D2) is between 150 and 500 and ROI (J2) is <= 3 then true or false.
5. If the price (D2) is >= 500 and ROI (J2) is <= 2.5 then true or false.
```

Comment: Can you us the code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you asked here is the formula:

```
=IF(AND(D2<=20,ROI(J2)<=10),"Output1",IF(AND(D2<60,ROI(J2)<=5),"Output2",IF(AND(D2<150,ROI(J2)<=4),"Output3",IF(AND(D2<500,ROI(J2)<=3),"Output4",IF(AND(D2>=500,ROI(J2)<=2.5),"Output5",FALSE)))))
```

Comment: First If is correct, but lock at the rest. You typed that if D2 is less than 60, then... There should be, if D2 is between 20 and 60, then... Am I right?

Comment: You can go with `AND(D2>20,D2<60,ROI(J2<=10))` but if it fails at <= 20 the value is surely >20 so I'll just ask if it is <60. The problem would be if you have values that are >20 and have ROI(J2)>5. For those cases, if those exist, you would need to apply the correction you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The formula is working. I forgot to input one more condition. The condition is: if D2=0 then "Neutral". How can I do it?

Comment: `=IF(AND(D2<=20,ROI(J2)<=10),"Output1",IF(AND(D2<60,ROI(J2)<=5),"Output2",IF(AND(D2<150,ROI(J2)<=4),"Output3",IF(AND(D2<500,ROI(J2)<=3),"Output4",IF(AND(D2>=500,ROI(J2)<=2.5),"Output5",IF(D2=0, "Neutral",FALSE))))))`

Comment: It's not working. :( Maybe, cause I have in the D2 field a currency ( example: € 0.00)?

Comment: If your € 0.00 is just formatting choice there should be no problem. But just in case it is try `VALUE(D2)=0`

Answer (score 0):

The following is a bit shorter and easier to read:

=IFERROR("Output"&MATCH(1,(D2>={0,20,60,150,500})*(D2<={20,60,150,500,99999})*(J2<={10,5,4,3,2.5}),0),FALSE)

Comment: This assumes the lowest value for D2 is 0 and the highest value is 99999. And in the above formula there should be a '*' between each ')('. No sure why my copy/paste missed the asterisk out...